# Change a number value to negative based on another separate textbox value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I have a report in Microsoft VS 2010.  It contains various fields.  One of the fields is Order Type.  One of the other fields is Quantity Sold.  I want to be able to make the Quantity Sold value a negative number if the Order Type is a certain value.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will negate the value under some condition:

```
select OrderType,
  case when OrderType = 42 then -QuantitySold else QuantitySold end as QuantitySold
  from StuffThatWasSold
```